# Как организовать разветвление в схеме?

Tags: блок-схема, proteus

У меня есть три 74LS74 триггера U1:A, U1:B, U2:A и два логических елемента - И и ИЛИ. Как можно организовать вычисление U1:A И U1:B если U2:A равен нулю, иначе U1:A ИЛИ U1:B?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *если U2:A равен нулю* (то что? ответ 0 или 1?), *иначе U1:A ИЛИ U1:B*

Answer (score 0):

Если 0 при отсутствии сигнала (при ноле с U2) нужен ноль, то нужно с U1  5 и 9 выводы подключить на вход U3,  а выходы с U2 и U3 на вход U4. Результат - выход U4.

Тогда получим...

```
А B U2 Q-U3 Q-U4
0 0  0  0   0
1 0  0  1   0
0 1  0  1   0
1 1  0  1   0
0 0  1  0   0
1 0  1  1   1
0 1  1  1   1
1 1  1  1   1
```

Если же надо наоборот, то вместо Q-U3 берем Q-U3-инверсный, тогда будет так

```
А B U2 Q-U3 Q-U4
0 0  0  0   0
1 0  0  1   1
0 1  0  1   1
1 1  0  1   1
0 0  1  0   0
1 0  1  1   0
0 1  1  1   0
1 1  1  1   0
```